# LICENSE text in build folder

Tags: mit, copyright, license-notice, website, license-file

When I build my site using create-react-app build, it creates a main.779c7054.js.LICENSE.txt which contains the license texts of the dependencies. In this case I am using Next.js and lets say I am using react-icons (licensed under MIT) by importing it to my component.js. The license says - "The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.". Do I need to include the MIT license text manually? if yes, where do I add it? or is the text already there in the source of node_modules and I don't need to do anything about it?

When I searched the build folder of the website created using Next.js I could find other license texts but there were no license text for react-icons package.

```
 *
 * Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
...

 * Copyright 2017 Google LLC
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
...
etc
```

Comment: You wrote "*...or is the text already there in the source of node_modules...*" Why don't you take a look and tell us?

Comment: @Martin_in_AUT it's not there, I wrote it in the last line :)

Comment: You wrote that the text is not in your build folder. Maybe you look at the source folder on the web.

Comment: @Martin_in_AUT in the node_module folder there's the LICENSE.txt that is there in GitHub but in the source folder on the web there's no license information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to manually add the the MIT license language at the end of the license.txt file (if it is not already there). Based on your description, React does not seem to be perfectly include everything that is required.

Maybe each of the icons includes license and attribution language within their code. In that case it would not be necessary to add additional language in the licenses.txt and notices.txt files.